# What are the files with a com prefix

Tags: macos, filesystems

I've seen many files start with a `com` on my machine, eg. `com.apple.mail`, anybody know what is the `com` stands for?

Comment: The same thing it means at the end of a hostname.

Answer (score 3):

This style of naming is a common practice (mostly in [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)) to help give code packages a unique [namespace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) to avoid naming conflicts in programming.

The standard specifies that the namespace begins with a [top level domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), with the inverse of the domain name of the company distributing it being common practice. That is, if the package is produced by example.com, its unique namespace might look like *com.example.unique.module*.

So, as pointed out in the comments, it means the same thing as it normally does at the end of a domain. It is simply being used for a different purpose.

Comment: Note that the namespace prefix should be the full domain name of the company/organization/whatever, in reverse order. So subdivision.division.company.co.uk's namespace would be `uk.co.company.division.subivision` (and would be followed by something like `.programname`).